# Regular Expression to exclude a list of words

Tags: regex, string

I am requested to enforce a regex behavior that will allow a user to fill a certain field under the following behavior:

```
^[a-z A-Z0-9\s]+$
```

However, in addition, I have a list of certain words that the user should not be allowed to insert.

I've used the following RegEx:

```
^((?!WordA|WordB).)[a-z A-Z0-9\s]+$
```

However, this disables any string starting with these words, while I need to disable only strings that are EQUAL to the words.

Any suggestion?

Comment: What system are you working with? Wouldn't it be easiest to keep the regex and then check if the field is not equal to a value in the blacklist?

Comment: simple fix mate: `^(?!(WordA|WordB)$)[a-z A-Z0-9\s]+$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is make the negative lookahead assure that the strings don't don't after each word like so:

```
^(?!(WordA|WordB)$)[a-z A-Z0-9\s]+$
```

Also, your part here: `[a-z A-Z0-9\s]` should really be `[a-zA-Z0-9\s]` (without the space) since `\s` matches spaces.

Comment: KISS, `^(?!Word[AB]$)[a-z A-Z0-9\s]+$`

Comment: @AvinashRaj i know you're trying to be clever and all but WordA and WordB are merely placeholders for other words and we can't be sure they could reduce down to that. Additionally, you also left the unnecessary space in the character block. So much for KISS

Comment: ya, don't see the char class.. but instead of writing the whole word, try to combine them both.

Comment: @AvinashRaj i dont think you quite understand what i just said so we'll leave it at a disagreement